# TurboGears for ecommerce

Tags: e-commerce, turbogears2

Is there a good Open Source shopping cart implementation for TurboGears?  (I found Satchmo for Django, but I'm coming up empty handed for TurboGears.)  I'd like to avoid reimplementing this particular set of wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I do not believe there is.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [stroller](https://bitbucket.org/axant/stroller) it's a library to add ecommerce features inside turbogears2 apps. It supports both manual payments handling, dispatching and paypal payments. It is meant to be used without forcing users registration.

It is still in playground status and is missing documentation, but should be quite easy to mount it inside your app and start playing with it.